# Yaml File escape characters in multiline string

Tags: pyyaml

I want to use `\n` character in multiline string but YAML doesn't allow me to use `\n` character. How can I use `\n` character.

My YAML:

```
treeroot:
    branch1:
        name: >
            hello my friend\n how are you ?
            i am fine and you ?\n
            yes\nthanks
        branch1-1:
            name: Node 1-1
    branch2:
        name: Node 2
        branch2-1:
            name: Node 2-1
```

I know, we can use `\n` character in single line mode but I want use it in multiline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'single-line' mode in YAML. You have scalars that represent strings and they can be plain (no quotes), single and double quoted. Apart from that, in block-style, you have literal and folded style.

Literal and folded style are always multiline (assuming you count the line with the `|` resp. the `>`), but the other scalars can be multiline as well. In the later case double new-lines in the string are transformed into newlines and other new-lines into spaces. Since escaping with backslash is only allowed in double quoted strings the following YAML is what you need to use:

```
treeroot:
    branch1:
        name: "hello my friend\n how are you ?
            i am fine and you ?\n
            yes\nthanks"
        branch1-1:
            name: Node 1-1
    branch2:
        name: Node 2
        branch2-1:
            name: Node 2-1
```

The value for the first key 'name' is the same as if specified as

```
"hello my friend\n how are you ? i am fine and you ?\n yes\nthanks"
```